# Python/Kivy: initialize switch after startup (w/o running on_active)

Tags: python, properties, kivy, switch-statement

I am facing a problem with the Kivy widget **Switch** and was not able to find a solution. Each topic on the Internet deals with "Working with the *active* property", which is understandable to me. But I want to **set/initializie the start-up active value** depending on the current environment within the program.

In my case: I have a Wifi Power-Plug which can be already running. So in this case when the app starts I want the switch with **active: True**. If the plug is deactivated, the switch shall start with **active: False**

Normaly you can do this from the main.py with sth. like:

```
if (getWifiState) == "OFF":
    self.ids[widgetName].active = False
else:
    self.ids[widgetName].active = True
```

Generally spoken this works and changes the state.
But here the problem: as soon as you are changing the switch value this way it behaves as if you were clicking on the switch, because the default **value = 0** → **change to 1** → **on_active: function()** will be called. But I need a solution which allows me just to change the start value without running the on_active property.

**Potential solution:**
Probably I have to put logic into my .kv file so that during the switch initialisation the correct start parameter will be set. But why?
Or is there another way to do so?

Appreciate your help

Tried to put logic to my active property in .kv-File, but this did not work.

Comment: You can initialize a variable (perhaps named `ignore_on_active`) to `True` early in your code. Then, in the `on_active()` method, you just return if `ignore_on_active` is `True`. Once your setup is complete, set `ignore_on_active` to `False`.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for trying to help me. I tried to implement your solution, but it does not lead to the needed result. If i exclude on_active() in the beginning by using another variable I just delay the problem.

As you mention yourself: after your setup is complete. So this might work in such situations, but in my case I need to finalize the setup first (which is actually my problem). Thanks anyway, the answer from @MST has helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    Switch:
        active: app.get_wifi_state()
        on_active: print(self.active)
'''

class Test(App):

    # method which return wifi status (replace implementation with your own)
    def get_wifi_state(self):
        return random.choice((True, False))

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

Test().run()
```

Comment: Great, this is so simple and works. Thanks a lot!

What I did wrong was the implementation of logic in the **on_active:** party. I tried to put basically a whole function in it, but it came not to my mind to refer to another function in the main.py which handles everything I need. This made the trick!